# Erro ao tentar realizar backup de base de dados em postgresql

Tags: postgresql, backup

Estou tentando realizar um backup de uma base de dados em Postgresql, porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

`erro ao ler objeto grande 118287: ERROR:  permission denied for large object 118287`

Pesquisei sobre o erro e encontrei as seguintes [informações](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/erro-de-large-object/27111)

Realizei os comandos indicados porém o erro persiste, alguém já passou por isso e encontrou uma solução?

Comment: como está fazendo o backup ? versão do banco... etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Desde a versão 9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-LO-COMPAT-PRIVILEGES), cada *large object* no PostgreSQL possui seu OID, assim como tabelas, índices etc., não devendo ser tratado como simples registro da tabela [`pg_largeobject`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-largeobject.html) e portanto não sendo automaticamente legível pelo usuário dono desta tabela. Você pode listar os *large objects* e seus respectivos donos via `psql` com o comando `\lo_list`:

```
nunks=# \lo_list
        Large objects
  ID   | Owner | Description 
-------+-------+-------------
 16820 | nunks | Smiley :D
(1 row)
```

Para conceder a um usuário os direitos de leitura do *large object* especificado na pergunta, utilize:

```
GRANT SELECT ON LARGE OBJECT 118287 TO nome_do_usuario;
```

Como seu caso implica na leitura de todo o banco, sugiro efetuar o backup com um usuário que tenha permissão para a leitura de todos os objetos. Um `SUPERUSER` sendo a solução mais simples de se manter, caso você só tenha problemas quando da execução de backups.

---

Outra alternativa é modificar o comportamento do DATABASE em questão utilizando a opção `lo_compat_privileges`. Assim todos os `large objects` do banco serão legíveis e alteráveis por todos os usuários. Entretanto, ***isso significa reduzir a segurança de seus dados***, algo que deve ser pesado no momento da decisão por tal alternativa. Para modificar o comportamento do banco, utilize um `ALTER DATABASE` com um superusuário:

```
ALTER DATABASE nome_do_banco SET lo_compat_privileges TO true;
```

---

A solução mais indicada para casos de uso com grande variedade de usuários criadores de *large objects*, conforme [esta resposta no DBA SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147737), talvez seja definir um ROLE em que todos eles estejam incluídos e, quando da criação de um *large object*, definir explicitamente o ROLE utilizado pela transação para que ele seja o dono efetivo dos objetos que cria. Dessa forma, todos os usuários pertencentes a esse ROLE poderão manipular tais *large objects*. Para definir qual ROLE será utilizado, logo antes de criar o *large object* utilize o comando:

```
SET ROLE nome_do_role;
```